# Automatically change branch in git

Tags: windows, git

I noticed that, on Windows, when I create a new branch in my repository using the shell, Git doesn't change the branch I am on. When using Linux, it does. How's that? Is there a possibility to change that, to the way Git in Linux does? (I'm very new to Git.)

Comment: Well how are you using git under Windows? Through PowerShell, Cygwin, or some GUI client?

Comment: What do you mean by "create a new branch"? Exactly what did you type or click?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a new branch and switch to it at the same time, use `git checkout -b <branchname>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was my Problem. Didn't use -b.

Comment: @AlexM. This command has the same effect in all versions of Git, irrespective of the platform. What your actual problem was is unclear.

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaking, but as I used the checkout command without "-b" in Linux it changed the branch automatically

Answer (score 0):

> I noticed that, on Windows, when I create a new branch in my repository using the shell, Git doesn't change the branch I am on

The commands for branching are the following:

```
# create branch and stay on the current branch
git branch <branch name>

# create a branch and switch to the new branch
git checkout -b <branch name>

# You can always create branch from any given commit/tag/branch etc you need
git checkout -b <SHA-1>/tag/branch
```

You can find in this answer a very useful information what it does and how to do it:

[How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. As ou can see, without -b it stays on the current branch. That was my problem.